# Is it correctly phrased or it is just a legal terminology?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, legalese

> All work completed after project inception will be billed as it is
> completed at the end of every calendar month as Work in Progress (WIP)
> until the conclusion of the project.

My classmate showed me this sentence and asked me what it means? At a glance, I thought I know what it means but after reading it multiple times, I question my own understanding of the sentence. I did a search and it turns out it is a legal phrase. I've no idea if it is a standard phrase but googling it does return quite a bit of results.

For this sentence ***"All work completed after project inception will be billed as it is completed at the end of every calendar month"*** I assume it means any work done after the project inception will be billed as it is by the end of every calendar month? The second part of the sentence ***"as Work in Progress (WIP) until the conclusion of the project"*** confused me. Colloquially, I can guess the meaning but I don't understand the choice of words and the sentence structure here.

I'm confused with the use of *All work completed*, *work-in-progress* and *conclusion of the project*. If it is *All work completed* and billed *as completed* at the end of the calendar month, why does it still be referred as *work-in-progress* and *until conclusion of the project*.

Is it correctly phrased or it is just a legal terminology?

If I were to substitute *completed* with the word *done*, will that still convey the same meaning?

> All work ***done*** after project inception will be billed as it is
> completed at the end of every calendar month as Work in Progress (WIP)
> until the conclusion of the project.

Comment: You should have written either _My classmate showed me this sentence and asked me "What does it mean?"._ or _My classmate showed me this sentence and asked me what it means._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for pointing out the mistake! Appreciate it

Comment: What's probably confusing you about this excessively tortuous / clumsy phrasing is that the word ***as*** is being used with two different senses in close proximity. So *...will be billed **as** it is completed* means ***at the time, once, after** [the work is completed]*, but *[billed] **as** Work in Progress* means ***under the heading of, by the name of** [Work in Progress]*.

Answer (score 2):

> All work completed after project inception will be billed as it is completed at the end of every calendar month as Work in Progress (WIP) until the conclusion of the project.

*"All work completed ... will be billed as it is completed... at the end of every calendar month"* means that monthly bills will be sent for individual work items that have been completed in that month. The bills will not be deferred until the completion of the whole project.

*"as work in progress"* means that the monthly bill for the completed work will be under the category of "work in progress". That is, the bill will be labeled "work in progress".

*"...until conclusion of the project"* means that the policy of monthly billing for individual completed items will apply until the project is over.

It defines a monthly pay-as-you-go policy.

As to your suggestion of "done", I think it would have a different nuance. The word "completed" suggests that the work is subdivided into defined units that can be said to be completed. For example, "all plumbing on the first floor is finished and ready for inspection."

"All work done" could mean just a total of hours worked.